# Why does adding an image to a div with display: table-cell add a whack-load of padding?

Tags: html, css

And how do I get rid of the padding?

Check this out ([jfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/Y89kY/)):

CSS:

```
.table
{
    display: table;
    height: 250px;

    border-color: black;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 250px;
    width: 50%;
    padding 0px;
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
}

.cell img
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="cell">
    <img src="">
</div>
<div class="cell">
    Caption
</div>
</div>
```

If the img element is removed, the padding in the left cell goes away. Weird thing is that I have padding set to 0 for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. What you're seeing is the default [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property in action, which is `baseline`.

If you change the cell's vertical alignment to `top` (or `middle` or `bottom` depending on where you want the text), you'll get what you want.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Y89kY/2/)**